# Is every bijective pseudograph homomorphism a pseudograph isomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

The term **pseudograph** describes a graph that may have  parallel edges and loops. Formally this is a triple $G = (V,E,\delta)$ with $V,E$ sets and a map $\delta \colon E \to (V \times V)/\sim$, where $(v,w) \sim (w,v)$ for all $v,w \in V$.

A **graph homomorphism** between graphs $G = (V,E,\delta)$ and $G' = (V',E',\delta')$ is then a pair $(f_V,f_E)$ with $f_V \colon V \to V'$ and $f_E \colon E \to E'$ such that
$$
\delta' \circ f_E = (f_V \times f_V) \circ \delta.
$$

When for such a homomorphism $f_V,f_E$ are both bijective, does $(f_V^{-1},f_E^{-1})$ define a graph morphism as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Multiply the equation $\delta' f_E = f_V^2 \delta$ with $f_E^{-1}$ on the right and with $(f_V^{-1})^2$ on the left, and you are done.